# How to disable Siri suggestions on iOS 15.6?

Tags: ios, notifications, siri

Recently, before I even log in to my iPhone running iOS 15.6, I receive Siri suggestions to call one of my calendar appointments, in addition to the reminder from the calendar appointment itself.  At present, I don't find the Siri suggestions to be well aligned with my needs, so they just cause cognitive noise.  I was not asked whether I wanted these suggestions:

I followed [this](https://www.businessinsider.com/how-to-turn-off-siri-suggestions) and [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/701132/how-to-disable-siri-suggestions-in-spotlight-search-on-iphone-and-ipad/) page to disable suggestions, but I have none of the switches shown.  The switches that I do have don't seem to be relevant:

[image]

**Is there no way to disable these Siri suggestions?**

P.S. I don't want to disable the "Allow notifications" switch because I want notifications -- just not Siri suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you scroll down some more, you'll get a list of apps.
Go into calendar, the last option is "Suggestion Notifications" - I would start there.
You can disable learning from calendar completely without turning off other apps.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll wait a bit before marking this as the answer because frankly, I don't know what any of these switches do.  Some provide explanation, but I can't say that it comes across clearly to me.

Comment: I've been on vacation for the past week, so not much notifications.  Therefore, not many situations which I can use to verify that the Siri suggestions for calendar notifications is disabled.  I'll keep an eye out for this in the coming week of non-vacation.

Comment: I agree with you, I think the UX around Siri Suggestions is overall quite poor. With some iOS updates, some suggestions are turned on by default, even if previously one had them turned off. The switches are unclear and buried in a mix of places. It's almost as if Apple is trying to force this cognitive noise on us. I find it annoying for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Siri, and I've disabled everything I could find in `Settings`. Since Apple will not allow us to remove the app completely, here's my solution:

- `Settings`, `Siri & Search`: I have disabled all options
- `Settings`, `Notifications`, `Siri Suggestions`: Disable the one option: `Allow Notifications`

Comment: I'll keep this in mind, but I want to be selective about how I make non-default settings.  Like I commented in another answer, I'm not entirely sure what most of these switches do.  Maybe I'll find one of the Siri features helpful one day.  But it wouldn't be too hard for iOS to say "We can have Siri do this and that in such-and-such an app when you do bladda bladda.  Would you like to try?".  But the greater likelihood is that I would prefer not to have most of these additional functions.

Comment: I keep wringing my hands about how my iPhone is getting slower, and a battery charge seems to be depleting faster.  I wonder if it is because of all this functionality that I don't use.  Hopefully, it isn't making the the processor run much more code than if the functionality wasn't there.  It's just taking up nonvolatile memory (or even working memory).  They really need two components to iOS: one for those wanting just a phone, browser, and apps; another for the AI digital companion.  Ideally, one should be able to opt out of the latter